# How to get xml properties chosen on child to pass to parent in LWR Experience Builder Site

Tags: lightning-web-components, child-to-parent, experience-builder-page, lwr

I have a parent wrapper for two cards in my markup with the cards nested within the parent wrapper.
How would I be able to still click on the card to dynamically change the card details? With them being nested inside of the wrapper, only the wrapper is clickable and only the wrappers xml properties are available.
Here is my code:
wrapper html:

```
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="card">
      <c-the-team-member></c-the-team-member>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <c-the-team-member></c-the-team-member>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is the card component html:

```
<template>
  <section class="team-member-container">
    <img src={setProfileImage} alt={memberName} class="team-member-photo" />
    <div class="team-member-details">
      <h3 class="team-member-title">{memberJobTitle}</h3>
      <h4 class="team-member-name">{memberName}</h4>

      <div class="team-member-social">
        <a href={memberLinkedInLink} class="linkedin"
          ><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
        </a>
        <a href={memberTrailheadLink} class="link"
          ><i class="fa fa-link"></i
        ></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
```

It's JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";
import ASSET_PATH from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/SUP_resources";

export default class TheTeamMember extends LightningElement {
  @api memberImage;
  @api memberJobTitle;
  @api memberName;
  @api memberLinkedInLink;
  @api memberTrailblazerLink;

  get setProfileImage() {
    return ASSET_PATH + "/Assets/" + this.memberImage;
  }
}
```

And it's XML config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>56.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
            <property
        name="memberImage"
        type="String"
        label="Image"
        description="Team member's image as portrait i.e length is bigger than width."
        datasource="mathieu.jpg, marc.jpg"
      />
            <property
        name="memberJobTitle"
        type="String"
        label="Job Title"
        placeholder="e.g CEO, CTO, Solutions Developer"
        description="Position of team member to be displayed"
      />
            <property
        name="memberName"
        type="String"
        label="First and Last name"
        placeholder="e.g John Smith"
        description="Member full name without middle names"
      />
            <property
        name="memberLinkedInLink"
        type="String"
        label="LinkedIn URL"
        placeholder="e.g https://www.linkedin.com/in/john-smith/"
        description="Member linkedin profile link to be clicked and take user to member's LinkedIn profile page"
      />
            <property
        name="memberTrailblazerLink"
        type="String"
        label="Trailblazer URL"
        placeholder="e.g https://www.trailblazer.me/id/johnsmith/"
        description="Member linkedin profile link to be clicked and take user to member's Trailblaizer profile page"
      />
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

All the dynamic properties in the {} are coming from what the user would choose, or enter when building the site through experience cloud builder.

Is there perhaps a way in which one could drag and drop the card component into the wrapper instead of having it nested in the wrapper component markup?

This seems to be the one issue that I am still struggling with after a while of building a site in Experience cloud and honestly cannot find any information on how to implement it. Unless I am missing something - I may be stuck on this for so long that I can't see the way.

Comment: By "only the wrapper is clickable", did you mean that it's only clickable in the builder or on the published page?

Comment: @AntonKutishevsky - In the builder, I need to pass the info from the container to the cards. It will be used by non developers in order to change things by drag and drop like the standard builder works. 
I can click on the container, but it doesn't bring up the pop up to input the dynamic information. 
I placed the xml code on the parent component, and I am now trying to take whatever the user inputs send it to the child, and then the child will display it. 
Click container -> user input -> send to child -> child renders the info.

Comment: the child components can have different attribute values?

Comment: Correct. You can place whatever you want - based on the xml configs.

Comment: I see. Well, if the components require different configurations, then you won't be able to select them via builder having the wrapper component. Maybe you could create a custom metadata with the fields that replicate the child components' properties and render component for each record in metadata?